# populate media element with media library song

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I'm trying to populate a media element with a medialibary song

but the media element source property wont accept anything i try has it it, the source property seems to load filepaths or urls btu i want to access and load a song from the media libary

if another approach is easier what im actually trying to do is, load a mediaplayer song into a slider

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say, but even in Mango this is 100% **NOT** possible. You can only stream media off the internet or from your XAP.

To bind the slider value you would bind the Position of the mediaelement to it

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer"/>
<Slider Value="{Binding ElementName="MediaPlayer", Path="Position", Mode="TwoWay"/>
```

Comment: im not trying to stream, im just trying to use the slider on one of the phones local media library

MediaLibrary.Song

Comment: Yea I know. I said you can't its NOT POSSIBLE Microsoft WP7 DOES NOT allow you to do this. I'm saying you can ONLY Stream or play a media file store in your XAP

Comment: @user1153974 - MyKuLLSKI is saying that you can only stream or use a file located in your XAP. The MediaElement can not currently play songs from the `MediaLibrary`.

Comment: ah right ok i follow, then is it possible to get a medialibrary item into a slider?

Comment: Thanks @keyboardP I thought I was going crazy for a second

Comment: @user1153974 - No, there is no way at the moment because you can't set the playback position of a `Song` in the `MediaLibrary`. The only way to play a `Song` is to use the `MediaPlayer` and that doesn't have the ability to jump to a particular position. (I assume your slider is being used to move to specific parts of the song).

Comment: The MediaElement does have a Position Property so I don't see why not and it has a Clock

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI - OP is asking to play a `Song` from the MediaLibrary. You yourself wrote that the `MediaElement` is incapable of playing `Songs` (i.e. any audio file from the `MediaLibrary`). In order to play a song from the `MediaLibrary`, OP has to use the `MediaPlayer` *not* a `MediaElement`. The `MediaPlayer` has no `Position` property, so OP can not attach a slider to a song retrieved from the MediaLibrary.

Comment: @keyboardP ok ok now I get you. Yea your right. The only way to do this is by unind a MediaElement

Answer (score 2):

To play any `Song` file retrieved from the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx), you have to use the [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx). Unfortunately, the `MediaPlayer` has no `Position` property which means you cannot programmatically set the position of the audio file. This means that it's not possible to attach a slider to the `MediaPlayer` in order to use it to change position.

As MyKuLLSKI mentioned, you can use a `MediaElement` to change the position of an audio file. However, you can't use a file retrieved from the `MediaLibrary` in the `MediaElement` (you can only use a `stream` or a file you have included within the XAP).

So, in your case, if you need to retrieve a song from the `MediaLibrary`, then you are limited to the [methods available to the MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer_methods.aspx) (which does not support positioning).

Comment: That sucks!

has anybody thought of any ways/ideas to do this, i cant see much on google, but maybe one of you guys has found something?